# Store Content of Wordpress site in mysql for language translation

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Is it possible to store the data content of a `Wordpress` website into `MySQL` database?

Case: I want to develop a `wordpress` website in `english` and `japanese` language. I want to have my ENGLISH content saved into the `MySQL` database.
Then I will also save my `japanese` translation of the `english` content also into the `MySQL` database in `wordpress`.

So that whenever the user clicked on the flag of `english` it will load the `english` content coming from the `database`, then vice-versa.

Note: The translation is manual, and I don't want to use any third party software like `google translate`, and `language plugins` in `wordpress`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

When I work with multilanguage I used to:

- Text in the _e('string','domainname')
- create a .po file which is basically a database of the words available for translations.
- Manage every translation with the plugin [Loco Translate](https://cl.wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/)

Hope it helps!